# Calculating sha1 in Node.js returns different result than in PHP

Tags: node.js, hash, base64, sha1

I'm calculating SHA1 using the following PHP code:

```
$hash = base64_encode(sha1($password.$key, true).$key);
```

But when I do this in Node.js, it does not give me the same result:

```
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(password + key).digest('base64');
```

Why are the results different?

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code, you're appending the key to the sha1 before passing it to `base64`:

```
sha1($password.$key, true).$key
```

In order to replicate that in Node.js, you'll need to do the same:

```
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(password + key).digest('hex');
var result = new Buffer(hash + key).toString('base64');
```

**Edit:** after looking at the [PHP docs on `sha1`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php), it looks like the second parameter being passed to `sha1` is going to return non-hex data:

> If the optional raw_output is set to TRUE, then the sha1 digest is instead returned in raw binary format with a length of 20, otherwise the returned value is a 40-character hexadecimal number.

So in order for the two snippets to function the same, you'd also need to modify the PHP to not pass that parameter:

```
$hash = base64_encode(sha1($password.$key).$key);
```

Comment: Continues to give different results

Comment: @GENTEBETA try removing that second "true" parameter from your PHP function?

Comment: @GENTEBETA that second parameter is going to make the PHP return an unencoded string instead of a hex string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append key in the nodejs:

```
// php
$hash = base64_encode(sha1($password.$key, true).$key);
                                     // see this ^^^^

// node
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(password + key).digest('base64') + key;
                                                                // add this ^^^^^^
```